# Bind or cast ListBox.ObjectCollection to ObservableCollection<string>

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

I need to modify a badly written program in order to add a new functionality while changing as least as possible of the original code.

The task is the following: I have 4 listbox on which items are programmatically added using listbox.items.add(item) at random intervals. They don't use datasource. I need to detect when some of the listbox stops adding new items and send an email alerting the situation.

I created a new class and tried to bind the items to a BindingList or ObservableCollection without success. This is what I got by now:

On main form:

```
listBoxTime1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Items", _inactividadController, "Items1")
        {
            DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged,
            ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never //because listbox.items is read only
        });
```

On my _inactividadController:

```
public ListBox.ObjectCollection Items1 { get; set; }
```

The binding works, I can access items as an array, but I'd love to convert Items1 to ObservableCollection so I can benefit from INotifyCollectionChanged.

Any other approach is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Why not using the `DataSource` property which specifically provided for binding the list portion of the `ListBox`?

Comment: DataSource is always null, as items are added using Listbox1.Items.Add(item)